# Django forms cache populating form

Tags: python, django

i'm populating the choices of a form in django,

The problem is that when i see it in the browser, the year list is fine according to the database, but when i change some date in database, the year select list doesn't update.

```
class PlanForm(forms.Form):

    def get_prices():
        return forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=map(
                lambda x: (
                    x.pk, 
                    (
                        unicode(x.length) 
                        + _(' Day Listing / ') 
                        + unicode(x.pics) 
                        + _(' Photos: ') 
                        + _('$ ') 
                        + unicode(x.price)
                    ),
                ),
                Pricing.objects.filter(
                    enable=True,
                    site=settings.SITE_ID,
                ),
            ),
            label=_('Plans'),
            widget=forms.RadioSelect
        )

    def get_options():
        return forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=map(
                lambda x: (
                    x.pk, 
                    (
                        unicode(x) 
                        + _(' : $') 
                        + unicode(x.price)
                    ),
                ),
                PricingOptions.objects.filter(
                    enable=True,
                    site=settings.SITE_ID,
                )
            ),
            label=_('Ads Options'),
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            required=False
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'passou no init'
        super(PlanForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pricing'] = self.get_prices()
        self.fields['pricing_options'] = self.get_options()


    pricing = get_prices()
    pricing_options = get_options()
```

I try this code, but I get the error

> get_prices() takes no arguments (1 given)

how can I sove this?

Answer (score 0):

class methods (e.g. `get_prices`) need at least one argument `self` which gets populated with the class instance calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

Add [@staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator to your methods. Python be default assume functions defiened inside a class as a method and passes 'self' as first argument. `staticmethod` prevents this default behaviour.

```
class PlanForm(forms.Form):

    @staticmethod
    def get_prices():
        return forms.ChoiceField(choices=map(lambda x: (x.pk, unicode(x.length) + _(' Day Listing / ') + unicode(x.pics) +  _(' Photos: ') + _('$ ') + unicode(x.price)  ), Pricing.objects.filter(enable=True,site=settings.SITE_ID)),label=_('Plans'), widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    @staticmethod
    def get_options():
        return forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=map(lambda x: (x.pk, unicode(x) + _(' : $') + unicode(x.price)), PricingOptions.objects.filter(enable=True,site=settings.SITE_ID)),label=_('Ads Options'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'passou no init'
        super(PlanForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pricing'] = self.get_prices()
        self.fields['pricing_options'] = self.get_options()


    pricing = get_prices()
    pricing_options = get_options()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
class PlanForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'passou no init'
        super(PlanForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pricing'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=map(lambda x: (x.pk, unicode(x.length) + _(' Day Listing / ') + unicode(x.pics) +  _(' Photos: ') + _('$ ') + unicode(x.price)  ), Pricing.objects.filter(enable=True,site=settings.SITE_ID)),label=_('Plans'), widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        self.fields['pricing_options'] =  forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=map(lambda x: (x.pk, unicode(x) + _(' : $') + unicode(x.price)), PricingOptions.objects.filter(enable=True,site=settings.SITE_ID)),label=_('Ads Options'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

Comment: worked, but would call the get_prices method within the init?